# Display flex and bootstrap .col-md-20 doesnt work properly in safari on Iphone 6 or plus

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox

I am having a strange trouble with mobile displaying on mobile in Safari browser. The problem is that it doesn't respect the display flex and bootstrap .col-md-20 on Iphone 6 or plus.
I still having another problem on icon in mobile menu on the same case.

The behavior is that:

[The second column is broking and font-awersome icon too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5EAV.png)

In Chrome this behavior is not happening:

[Works fine on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRdDR.png)

I tried to add this but do not solve my problem:

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-color-index:0) {
  #search {(;
       background:blue;
       width: 100%
   );}
   .fx {(;
        display: -webkit-box;
    );}
    nav.header-user-links.u-in-blk.mid {(;
         margin: 0 auto;
         text-align: center;
     );}
   .header-navigation-options{(;
          width: 100%;
    );}
    .product-box-image-link img {(;
        /*webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);*/
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    );}
    ul.fx-main.mc-wrap.note-wrap {(;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    );}
    input.form-control.cart-product-quantity {(;
        padding: 0 10px;
    );}
    .toggle-categories {(;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    );}
}



.fx.fx-rows.row {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  @include displayFlex;
  @include flexWrap(wrap);
}

  .fx.col-md-20.col-sm-4.col-xs-6 {
    /**
     * Height AUTO is important, because adding flex to the child makes it vertically
     * stretch by default. So that means height: 100% won't work.
     */
    height: auto;
    //IE fallback
    display: inline-block;
    //Modern Browsers
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    height: auto;
    //IE fallback
    display: inline-block;
    @include flexboxDisplay;
    @include flex(0 0 auto);

    ...

    /**
     * For some unknown reason, it still didn't work until I subracted 1% from
     * the width of each breakpoint I was using.
     */
   }
    @media screen and (min-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'lg')) {
      width: percentage((3 / 12)) - 1%;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'md')) {
      width: percentage((4 / 12)) - 1%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'sm')) {
      width: percentage((6 / 12)) - 1%;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how to solve that?

```html
<div class="fx col-md-20 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="product-box">
        <a class="product-box-image-link u-blk u-center-blk" href="http://marketplace.app/teste/produto/new-hNng" role="link">
            <img class="u-blk u-center-blk" src="http://marketplace.app/assets/img/product/default.jpg" alt="new" role="img">
        </a>

        <h2 class="product-box-title">
            <a class="product-box-link text-uppercase" href="http://marketplace.app/teste/produto/new-hNng" title="new">
                new
            </a>
        </h2>

        <div class="fx fx-rows fx-space-justify">
                                                <div class="product-box-price">
                        <small class="product-box-business-model">
                            Varejo
                        </small>

                                                    <h3 class="spotlight-product-price">
                                R$  25,00
                            </h3>
                                            </div>
                            
            
                    </div>

        <div class="product-box-footer">
            <a class="spotlight-product-sku u-blk" href="http://marketplace.app/teste" title="Teste">
                Teste
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give a fiddle?

Comment: Bootstrap uses 12 col grid, there's no `col-md-20` class.

Comment: The problem is current on production environment and there are a lot of classes involving it so it will will take a lot of time to add this om  fiddle. So I am giving you a link instead: https://www.rock2you.com.br/categorias/instrumentos-musicais